# Objective C generate random id for object that does not repeat

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to generate unique ids for object identification, I've come across `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]`, can it be used for unique identification? or there's a better approach for generating?

Comment: A poor-man's unique ID is the clock ticks to, say, a millisecond, in decimal, combined with a circular counter.

Answer (score 3):

Yes: `NSUUID` generates a unique ID.

From Apple:

> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally
>   Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit
>   values. UUIDs created by NSUUID conform to [RFC
>   4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) version 4 and are created
>   with random bytes.

From [RFC 4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt):

> A UUID is 128 bits long, and can guarantee uniqueness across space and
>   time.

Answer (score 0):

You may use the following

```
CFUUIDRef udidCFUUIDRef = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
NSString *UUIDString = (NSString *) CFBridgingRelease(CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, udidCFUUIDRef));
```